# Where is powercfg located?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, powercfg

I need to use the [powercfg tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from my service and I was curious, if it was safe to call it as such:

```
powercfg <parameters>
```

instead of providing a full path to it. The reason I'm thinking about it is that I keep reading security warnings in Microsoft's documentation that "an attacker" can place a *rogue powercfg* into the folder with my process's executable that may be called instead of the *real* powercfg.

The question then is where powercfg located?

Comment: `The Old New Thing` has a variety of articles about this. The gist of it is that as long as you secure your application's installation directory (putting it into `Program Files` for example, which requires admin rights to write into) you don't have to worry about rogues planting files your directory: They already HAVE root on the host. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/31/10364271.aspx for example.

Answer (score 0):

Powercfg is located usualy: 
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe
Did you mean windows powercfg tool yes?

Comment: Well, yes and no. It depends on whether or not your process is running on a 64-bit OS, and whether or not your process is 32-bit.